# openlayer markers located at the wrong place

Tags: openlayers, marker

I have create a marker, and I have to update it postition.

So I use the `moveTo` method:

```
marker.moveTo(marker.map.getPixelFromLonLat(lonlat));
```

[Live Exmaple:](http://jsfiddle.net/3pPB3/)

Once you move the map, the marker will be located at the wrong place, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution through the openlayer maillist:

Instead of using :

```
marker.moveTo(marker.map.getPixelFromLonLat(lonlat));
```

You should use:

```
marker.moveTo(marker.map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(marker.map.getPixelFromLonLat(lonlat)));
```